# Computer Janitor

Tags: cleanup, libraries

I'm willing to use Computer Janitor but I'm afraid to lose some important libraries.

Is it secure to use Computer Janitor?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Computer Janitor is being dropped in the next version of Ubuntu - mainly because nobody used it and the serious perceived issues that it could break your system with some of its suggestions.

I would recommend you take a closer look at either Ubuntu Tweak (from [here](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/downloads/)) or Bleachbit (from software centre)

There is an [AU question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33149/is-ubuntu-tweak-considered-to-be-a-safe-program) here with regards to Ubuntu Tweak.

I haven't found a similar question for BleachBit - but [this AU question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2243/ccleaner-equivalent) may help.