# After running computer-janitor, ubuntu crashed ( Possibly deleted configuration packages)

Tags: 10.04

I have some problem, so can anyone help me ?

After I have run computer janitor, my computer crashed. What happens ;

- All of the sets are gone.
- I cannot see my Desktop ( I think it erased image of the ubuntu ) .
- I can not use usb ( In terminal, error message is thrown "port cannot be used" )

After I opened my computer, at left corner, there is a terminal. Moreover, background of desktop is colored by violet ( I think it is violet ) .

What I can use ;

- I can only  use terminal.
- No program is erased ( I can use them over terminal )
- No file is erased

How can I save my computer ?

Without loosing any file, I can upgrade to any version of ubuntu. ( remember : I can only use terminal. )

My other question : how can upgrade ubuntu to any version of ubuntu over using Tty ?

EDIT :

```
 lsb_release -a 

 No LSB modules are available
 Distributor ID : Ubuntu 
 Description : Ubuntu 19.04.4 LTS
 Release : 10.04
 Codename: lucid

 uname -a

 Linux <name> 1.6.32-41-generic #90-Ubuntu SMP Tue may 22 11:29:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: can you specify which Version of Ubuntu you are using , for someone to help you with upgrading

Comment: @tijybba how can I know. Can you recommend me any command, which can be used in tty, in order to see version of ubuntu ? ( I think ubuntu 10.04 64 bit )

Comment: lsb_release -a  and uname -a,  try that in tty

Comment: @tijybba see edit

Comment: @ gcc- its weird 19.04.4 LTS, anyways try **sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop** , it will try to install the deleted packages that janitor deleted. Use of Janitor is not Recommended.

Comment: @tijybba can you fix my question and make your comment as answer ?

Comment: Did that work . Then i will post it as answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3770/discussion-between-gcc-and-tijybba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop** , it will try to install the deleted packages that janitor deleted. Use of Janitor is not Recommended

Also for recovering deleted file try [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33800/how-to-recover-deleted-files-and-folders) .

And use of janitor is not recommended as fossfreedom said [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50664/computer-janitor)

> Computer Janitor is being dropped in the next version of Ubuntu -
>   mainly because nobody used it and the serious perceived issues that it
>   could break your system with some of its suggestions.