# How can I change the name "Rubbish Bin" to "Trash" (or "Recycle")

Tags: nautilus

A recent update (Ubuntu 10.04) has caused my *Trash* bin to be renamed to "Rubbish Bin".. I don't like this new name. How can I change it?

I've tried: `gconf-editor -> apps/nautilus/desktop -> trash_icon_name`
but that didn't work.

Also, `$HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs` has no entry for the Trash directory...

Comment: I like 'Rubbish Bin', sounds so Australian. :~)

Comment: @mike. I completely agree with you. It is very Australian, but because of that is stronly means rubbish which has been totally rejected, eg; domestic food waste, etc... I always `Shift-Delete` my rubbish files.. For me, my `Trash-1000` is solely for my potentially recycleable files. I can happily live with 'trash', as here it loosely means hard-rubbish, and "trash it!" means "destroy or wreck it, or chuck it out!" ... but I don't want to go rummaging through my *rubbish* :)

Comment: A different interface language should solve it, if that is an acceptable solution. You'll get 'Trash' with English USA, that's what I use.

Comment: I'm don't know if this is the problem, but regardless of all other `locale` values being set to US (now), this line `export LANGUAGE="en_US:en"` in my `~/.profile` has no effect, and I still wind up with `LANGUAGE="en_AU:en"` in my bash `locale` output. So something seems to be changing `LANGUAGE` to AU after `~/.profile` is run, but I don't know where. It isn't in my `/bashrc`... **and** this has only happened since I rebooted yesterday (after updating 2-3 days ago)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an option to select the interface language at the login screen. I've just tried loggin out and selecting Australian English, and now have the 'Rubbish Bin' in Nautilus. Select English USA and you should get 'Trash'.

Comment: That worked... Thanks.. you've saved the day (well, mine at least ) ... my logon bypasses all the option stuff: its good to know those options are there.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may have set yourself to a different location (eg. UK) as I believe that is the name for it when using UK english.

Comment: Interesting.. I'll check that out.. I haven't changed anything myself, though something else may have... (I"m back) .. I've checked my locale and it looks the same as before: all `AU`.. eg. `LANG=en_AU.UTF-8`  `LANGUAGE=en_AU:en` `LC_CTYPE=en_AU.UTF-8` .. But in any case, Is there some way you know of to change *only* this Trash title.

Comment: PS.. I don't know my locale settings particularly well, but I must say that `LANGUAGE=en_AU:en` looks a bit unfamiliar to me.. I thought (prior to this) that all my settings were suffixed with `UTF-8`.. but I'm not 100% sure of that, and I don't know how or what to check... I just checked a 10.04 VM and it doesn't have have the `LANGUAGE=` setting... The VM's nautilus names the trash directory as: `Wastebin`

Answer (score 1):

probably the easiest way you can can change it is to [install ubuntu tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) and under the desktop icon settings you can name it anything you want.

Comment: matt. thanks for the suggestion, and I appreciate that it may well work, but because I keep away from (most) things which [aren't in the repository](http://askubuntu.com/a/33154/2670), and because I really want to know what has caused this and how to fix it more directly (ie. conf files, etc), I'll have to let this option pass...

Comment: fair enough, I'm pretty sure it is in the repos 10.10 onwards though. I still don't understand why  /apps/nautilus/desktop/trash_icon_name isnt working for you. I cant try anything else as I'm not on an Ubuntu machine.

Comment: you changed the value form integer to string yes? Oh and this would only change the desktop icon and not the panel icon name.

Comment: *@matt:* Yes, it is definitely set: `gconftool-2 --get /apps/nautilus/desktop/trash_icon_name` returns my value of `TRASH`, but I don't have any desktop icons (I favour the keyboard), and icons spoil my desktop pic, which at the moment happens to be a picture of midnight on a moonless starless night in the middle of an arctic winter, sort of the opposite of a polar bear in a blizzard. :) .. but, thanks for the good suggestions ... I hadn't realized it only applied to the desktop icon (although the key-name is a bit of a give-away, come to think of it)