# Is there a way I can rename Trash to Crap?

Tags: filesystem, xdg

I was trying to Rename the folder **Trash** to **Crap**.

I did this

I first ran `cd /home/username/.local/share/`

Now my present working directory is `/home/username/.local/share`

then when I typed `ls` I could see the folder **Trash**.

then I renamed it to **Crap** by typing `mv Trash Crap`

and then when I again typed `ls` I could see that the folder was renamed to **Crap** but on the launcher when I open the Trash folder it's still named as **Trash** and not **Crap**. Why is that so?

Comment: If you rename Trash to Crap, and then logout and login again and go to `~/.local/share`, there will be another Trash folder created. I think you need to change some other XDG settings as well (or perhaps use a symlink): see the [trash spec](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/trash-spec).

Comment: @Mik No I just logged out and logged in again. There is not folder named trash...its still crap

Comment: I realise now -it will create another Trash folder once you delete something-I should try it.

Comment: @Mik Yeah a new folder Trash is created... so there is no way you can rename it?

Comment: I think Trash and other desktop standards are governed by the XDG settings, but it might be possible to change the name by tweaking those XDG settings. Without further research I'm not quite sure which setting it is, however.

Comment: Read the [Trash specification](http://www.ramendik.ru/docs/trashspec.html), it has the word trash placed everywhere. So as [Mik](http://askubuntu.com/users/76204/mik) said, it may need a lot of research

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change the name "Rubbish Bin" to "Trash" (or "Recycle")](http://askubuntu.com/questions/85241/how-can-i-change-the-name-rubbish-bin-to-trash-or-recycle)

Comment: When using English it is called `Rubbish bin` so a method might be to copy the translation to a new name and then change Trash to Crap. This would only affect the launcher ;)

Comment: I have created an askUbuntu account just for voting this question up. Awesome.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yeah, you can abuse the translations system to do this.

Make a temporary text file using gedit

```
gedit /tmp/foo.po
```

and enter this text into it:

> msgid "Trash"
>
> msgstr "Crap"

Change to `/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES`

```
cd /usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES
```

And then apply changes

```
sudo msgfmt -o unity.mo /tmp/foo.po
```

Now restart unity to make the changes take effect.

```
unity --replace
```

---

*Source:* https://askubuntu.com/a/225023/17722

Answer (score 3):

[From the Freedesktop Trash Specification:](http://www.ramendik.ru/docs/trashspec.html)

> *For every user a “home trash” directory MUST be available. Its name
>   and location are `$XDG_DATA_HOME/Trash` ; `$XDG_DATA_HOME` is the base
>   directory for user-specific data, as defined in the Desktop Base
>   Directory Specification .*

So, no. It seems there is no way to rename the directory.

However, you can make a soft link with the name you want, and then hide the Trash directory:

```
ln -s ~/.local/share/Trash ~/.local/share/Crap
echo Trash > ~/.local/share/.hidden
```

Not every file explorer will honor this `.hidden` file, for example the terminal itself. However, it seems to work properly on Nautilus.

Comment: But won't the unity launcher will still show Trash instead of Crap?

Comment: So you want to rename Trash on Unity. I didn't understand that, sorry. Nope, you can't. Your best chance is modifying the .pot, I'll add another proposal.

Answer (score -3):

Go to http://ubuntu-tweak.com/
There you can download the program and use it to change it to whatever you want.  As for "Rubbish Bin," your settings probably has you in Australia.

Comment: That is for a trash icon on the desktop, not the trash bin in the Launcher. It's also advisable when giving a answer to show how to do something, not just provide a link.