# How to change Rubbish Bin to Trash system wide

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-mate, caja

In Ubuntu MATE 16.04.1 how can you change ***Trash*** to ***Rubbish Bin*** system-wide? Caja mainly uses trash and some rubbish bin, Plank only uses trash, I've tried other methods, but these are only for standard Ubuntu, and the directory is ://trash not ://rubbish.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/240431/is-there-a-way-i-can-rename-trash-to-crap

Comment: Doesn't work for me.