# How to delete all source codes and packages I have downloaded

Tags: 12.04, command-line, delete, source-code

I've got a question regarding how to delete all source codes that I've downloaded.

I think it just consumes a lot of space without any benefit yet!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How did you download the source codes - `sudo apt-get source <package-name>`? About the other question, please do post a new question :)

Comment: @nitstorm thanks dear, i've downloaded 'em using **Update manager** but i've unchecked the rep. recently. I wanna remove all source codes. I'll post another question, thanks again :D

Comment: You mean you want to clear the Package Caches installed through update manager.Or do you want to Uninstall the installed packages.

Comment: @tijybba i meant to remove source codes of packages. how can i know what source codes that have been downloaded?! where are they stored??

Comment: See the below @swift answer , and also visit the linked page for more reference.

Comment: @tijybba I saw it & have tried these commands before with no benifit! I'm gonna check the linked page soon. thanks :)

Comment: Then try manually deleting them from `/var/cache/apt/archives` , root access will be required to delete them,  **please refrain from deleting if dependency or partial update /upgrade like errors are seen**

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you read this Community Documentation article: [**Recover Lost Disk Space**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoverLostDiskSpace)

*From link:*

### How to find lost space

To check the amount of space being used for package storage, run:

```
du -h /var/cache/apt/
```

### How to Fix It

There are several system commands you can use to reduce or eliminate the number of locally stored packages.

- Remove **all expired packages** from `/var/cache/apt/archives` and `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial` that are no longer available for download:

  ```
  sudo apt-get autoclean
  ```

  "Not available for download" does not mean the user should save them - normally these files have been replaced or are no longer needed.
- Remove **all the packages** from `/var/cache/apt/archives` and `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial` folders:

  ```
  sudo apt-get clean
  ```
- Remove unneeded dependencies which are no longer needed:

  ```
  sudo apt-get autoremove
  ```

---

Synaptic ***custom filter*** practice can also help for search packages:

You can use this method for searching custom packages, but **I DON'T RECOMMEND IT** as universal method for cleaning.

[image: Settings -> Filters]

*You can choose different **Statuses** for New Filter :*

[image: New Filter with Status]

*And create different **Properties** :*

[image: New Filter with Properties]

Good Luck!

Comment: you are right; i wanna get more free space on my OS! I think **update manager** had installed source codes with applications as well. I wanna remove them from my system. above commands didn't help me! thanks anyway :D

Comment: then you should comment links in sourcelist which begin **deb-src** OR uncheck checkboxes for sources in repository settings ... then run `sudo apt-get update` and NEXT fix your space with commands above.   

Official guide have detailed practice for most cases about Recovering Missing Disk Space.

Comment: thanks a lot but I'll check it later cuz my Internet subscription will finish soon! I'll let you know later on :D

Answer (score 2):

I use the Janitor option in [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) that gets rid of a lot of extra space. Maybe this will delete your source files as well as it deletes all of the Update managers cached files.

Comment: would also add bleach bit to the list.

Comment: No really not recommended ,see [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33149/is-ubuntu-tweak-considered-to-be-a-safe-program). Use the in-built tools instead.