# How to speed up installation?

Tags: performance, cpu, ram

I have an Acer 4736z with 2gb Ram and ubuntu 12.04 is running too slow for my standards.

I would like to know if I am running useless processes that I am not aware of and remove packages I will never use.

How can I do that?

`free -m` output:

```
              total used free shared buffers cached
Mem:          1944  1627 316  0      15      340
-/+ buffers/cache:  1271 673
Swap:         1976  676  1300
```

Comment: Is it using more ram than required , post the output of `free -m`

Comment: total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1944       1627        316          0         15        340
-/+ buffers/cache:       1271        673
Swap:         1976        676       1300

Comment: I would suggest you to notice your `system monitor` , look for highest RAM or CPU eater process and post if found something unusual. Try `top` in terminal to view in CLI.

Comment: Will "sudo apt-get autoclean" make any difference?

Answer (score 2):

1. You could probably remove the indicator-messages service, but that won't save much.
2. Another option would be to run unity 2d or gnome-classic from the login screen. The 3d desktops use more computer to do "compositing" and newer software tends to consume more resources than older software. Unity uses compiz to do its compositing and it does seem to accumulate notable cpu time on my laptop.
3. The next time you want to install Ubuntu you could install the Xubuntu flavor of Ubuntu. It is built to be lighter weight.

Answer (score 1):

Run `sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove any useless packages.

Also I installed `ubuntu-tweak` and this has a janitor function for clearing up your system, but this is not recommended. See [How do I install Ubuntu-Tweak?](https://askubuntu.com/q/75454/18612) for instructions on how to get it.

Use the Software Center to remove any unwanted apps.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Use of janitor from Ubuntu-tweak is Really **Not Recommended** :)

Comment: Mind if I ask why I used it with no problems

Comment: I find the Janitor in Ubuntu Tweak is *much* safer to use than the Computer Janitor utility which used to be installed by default in Ubuntu. That being said, you should be careful if you do decide to use it. (I only use mine to clear out any kernels older than the two most recent, as well as my apt-cache.)

Comment: removing "useless packages" is not going to affect machine performance in any way, at least if the definition of "useless" is "not used by the system and eligible to be auto-removed". The OP will need to *uninstall* some packages which are currently *in use* and consume RAM when the system is running.

Comment: @markkirby - it is mainly because it is Third party PPA , i would not not trust such tool to clean my temp , or unwanted cache files. i read something about that [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33149/is-ubuntu-tweak-considered-to-be-a-safe-program). My only intention was to convey the use of inbuilt safer tools as mentioned in this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/3154/63025) .

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to install an Ubuntu derivative that is lighter, such as [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net).